# Deployment PHP App to Google App Engine took so long time

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

Hello I'm facing a problem today with GAE SDK which it took a lot of time to update my app, before that it was fast to upload and took minute or less than that.

Even so, I went to **Google Cloud Status Dashboard** to check and verify if GAE service is outage and it wasn't outage.

This is my [screenshot for my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5siqF.png), and this is [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kdb8.png) at the same time.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Has this got any better? Was it a one off?

Comment: @Tom Yeah still slow even last time when I did it took more than **20 minutes**.
I just updated a few files and not upload a new fresh application contains thousands of files!

Comment: I noticed your app was very large. Is all of that needed? Is any of it test or development libraries, like PHPUnit, that can be skipped? There is a syntax for that.

Comment: GAE SDK uploader works like **Git** which only upload changed files, to do that uploader needs to scan all files of course.
Before we moved from our old location I can update my App in less than a minute with our DSL. But, in new location we have a fiber connection and better speed in browsing, streaming & downloading.
Except, GAE uploader takes so long to update a punch of files.
Our App doesn't has any test library.